# Some help stretching columns using css

Tags: html, css

I have a very basic requirement of having a left menu (column) on the screen and content to the right of it. I have put up a basic code but it doesn't really solve what exactly I am looking for. First here is the code.

**The Html**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="left-column">Left Column</div>
    <div id="content">@RenderBody()</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**The CSS**

```
    html, body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;           /* width of whole page */
}

#header 
{
    height:25px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#left-column 
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:maroon;
}

#content 
{
    float:left;
    width:800px;

    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

This does lay out the contents but I was looking for following.

1. The left menu and the content column should be of equal height, that
   is, the smaller div (of Menu or Content) should stretch to line up
   with the larger div.
2. When the contents of both the div are less than the browser screen height, then both the div (menu and content) should stretch themselves to fit the screen height.

Can any one suggest the necessary modifications for achieving the above 2 conditions.

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/PFyvkHiz)***

Hi Nirvan You can do easily as like this

**Write this css**

```
    html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

#wrapper 
{
    margin:0 auto;

}
#header 
{
    height:25px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#left-column{
background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  bottom:0;
width:200px;
}
#content {
background:green;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  right:0;
  top:25px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

**Write this html**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>

  <div id="left-column">Left Column <br >Left Column <br >Left Column <br ></div>
    <div id="content">@RenderBody() </div>

  </div>
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/PFyvkHiz)***

Comment: Rohit, Thanks for the reply. It does solve my first requirement. The columns seems to be stretching. But the columns don't stretch to the bottom of the screen. Will it be possible to stretch them to the bottom of the window.

Comment: Rohit, Yes, exactly what I wanted. Nevertheless I will test it to see what happens if the contents of content div are very large. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Rohit, it fails when the contents of the content div are very large. Try repeating @RenderBody on vertically and then scroll to see the issue. Nevertheless, I got a lot of ideas from your code. I have pasted my code as one of the solutions. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solution which doesn't use faux columns. It uses concept of negative margins as explained at [enter link description here](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) The code below satisfies my both requirements mentioned in the question.

**The Html**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left-column">
            Left Menu
        </div>
        <div id="content">@RenderBody()</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Css**

```
    html, body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:100%;    
}

#header 
{
    width:1000px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height:25px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#container 
{
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:100%;
}

#container #left-column
{
    float:left;
    padding-top:25px;
    background:maroon;
    width:200px;
    padding-bottom:5000px;
    margin-bottom:-5000px;
}


#container #content
{
    float:left;
    padding-top:25px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    width:800px;
    padding-bottom:5000px;
    margin-bottom:-5000px;
}
```

regards,
NIrvan